# Render in less than 24 fps

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render a very heavy scene in Cycles. The scene should have around 10 seconds long. If I render the 240 frames (if it's done in 24 fps) is going to take to much time so I was wondering if I could render it in less than 24 fps and still have a fluid sensation of motion... 12 fps maybe? I don't want to have a stop motion felling.

Comment: If you already have a baked simulation that has 240 frames, it will still be 240 frames, no matter which playback speed you enter. The simulation will run for 20 seconds instead of 10, if you change it to 12 fps, but you still have to render 240 frames. I don't know if there is a way for time-scaling a bake. With a keyframed animation it's easy, in the timeline you can scale it with 0.5 on the X axis so that it's no longer 240 but 120 frames. Maybe someone else knows a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

12 would be your lowest choice but it depends on your animation content. If it has some fast movements they will become jerky at 12fps. For animations; a safe area to start from is 16-20 frames per second. An example is [Silent movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_film#Projection_speed) which were filmed with a frame rate around this range .

Comment: Thank you! It's has a cloth animation with some wind, so I think that I will go for 16...